# How do I find out if a printer is scan to email compatible with Office 365?

Tags: email, printer, smtp, office365, scanning

I have a Toshiba e Studio 282 that previously had scan to email going through an Exchange server. The Exchange server was decommissioned and the company got Office 365 instead. I tried inputting the SMTP settings for Office 365 but it did not work. Users are still getting the error: "Failed to connect to SMTP server". I was told that Office 365 needs to be set up for SMTP Relay in order for this to work and the printer needs to support TLS authentication. I have the "from" address as an active Office 365 email as well. If I change the settings for Office 365 and input the new from address, I get this error: "Invalid address specified in From: field". At this point I am thinking that the printer simply does not support the connection type or I am using the wrong set up.

If anyone could point me in the right direction, I would appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: "Failed to connect to SMTP server" means you're not successfully connecting to the O365 Exchange server. Since you're not even connecting, the SMTP relaying suggestions is not applicable.  What SMTP settings (server, port, etc.) are you actually using in Outlook to connect to the O365 Exchange server? Are those the same settings you're using in the scanner's email client settings?

Comment: Server: smtp.office365.com Port: 587 Encryption: TLS

These are the SMTP settings I used in the Toshiba. I changed the DNS to the same server (smtp.office365.com). Even with these settings, it still did not work.

Comment: And those are the same settings you used in working Outlook clients (on computers)? Using "Client SMTP Submission" (TLS over port 587) requires authentication, so is your eStudio authenticating with a user name and password?

Comment: Outlook settings are the same. Yes, it's set to authenticate on the Toshiba.

Answer (score -1):

Your dns server should not be smtp.office365...that server is not a dns server, it is an smtp server.  Use Google's dns server at 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4
I had the same issue until I put a valid dns server in the ip configuration.